# Equation of locus of points satisfied by $\frac{\left|z+3i\right|}{\left|z-6i\right|}=1$

Tags: complex-numbers

Equation of locus of points satisfied by $\frac{\left|z+3i\right|}{\left|z-6i\right|}=1$

The answer I got is $y=\frac{3}{2}$, but the answer given in my book is $y=-0.5x+2.25$

Can anyone please confirm which is the right answer

Edit: Sorry, the modulus was on each numerator and denominator, not for the whole thing, though I don't think this makes a difference.

My working

subbing $z=x+yi$ gives

$\frac{\left|x+yi+3i\right|}{\left|x+yi-6i\right|}=1$

$\frac{x^2+(y+3)^2}{x^2+(y-6)^2}=1^2$

Expanding brackets and then solving gives

$y=3/2$

Thank You

Comment: Please show us your workings, i.e. your work from which you "got is $y=\frac 32$.  Other wise, we cannot confirm your solution.  So, show us how you arrived at your answer, by editing your post to include it.

Comment: I think you're right. The equation says point $z$ is equidistant from $-3i$ and $6i$, which should be a horizontal line at $y=1.5$.

Comment: @amWhy I have done so now. Thanks

Comment: @JirapatSamranvedhya Thanks very much, that's how I thought about it first too.

Comment: NumberCruncher  Thank you for including your work!

Comment: It is probably worth remarking that $x$ can take any real value & the locus of point that satisfy $ \mid z +3i \mid = \mid z-6i \mid $ is $ z=x + \frac{3}{2}i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cut down on unanswered questions, here we go!

The book's answer is certainly wrong, as one readily sees by considering $z=\frac94i.$

Now, we clearly cannot have $z=6i$ as a solution, for then we have $\frac90=1,$ which is nonsensical. Consequently, the given equation is equivalent to $$|z+3i|=|z-6i|,$$ or, put another way, to $$\bigl|z-(-3i)\bigr|=|z-6i|.$$

Since $|z-w|$ is the distance from $z$ to $w$ for all $z,w\in\Bbb C,$ then the equation above says that $z$ is equidistant from $-3i$ and $6i.$ Readily, putting $z=x+iy,$ this is equivalent to saying that $(x,y)$ is equidistant from $(0,-3)$ and $(0,6),$ *i.e.*: $$\sqrt{x^2+(y+3)^2}=\sqrt{x^2+(y-6)^2}.$$ This is, of course, equivalent to your approach, and solving the preceding equation yields $y=\frac32,$ as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Given two points,
the set of points
equidistant from them
is the perpendicular bisector
of the line joining them.

If the points are
$(a, b)$ and
$(c,d)$,
the midpoint is
$((a+c)/2, (b+d)/2)$.

The slope of the line is
$\dfrac{d-b}{c-a}$,
so the slope of the normal
is the negative reciprocal
of this or
$-\dfrac{c-a}{d-b}
=\dfrac{a-c}{d-b}
$.

Therefore the equation
of the perpendicular bisector is
$\dfrac{y-(b+d)/2)}{x-(a+c)/2}
=\dfrac{a-c}{d-b}
$.

If $a=c=0$,
as in this case,
the equation is
$\dfrac{y-(b+d)/2)}{x}
=0
$
or
$y=(b+d)/2$.

In this case,
$b=-3$ and $d=6$,
so the equation is
$y
=(6-3)/2
=3/2
$.